# Golang MongoDb GridFs Testing

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a rest API implemented using Gorilla Mux in Golang. This API uploads/downloads files from MongoDb GridFs. I want to write integration tests for my API. 
Is there a `embedded MongoDb` package with `GridFs support` in Go? How do we test APIs using GridFs? Do we need to test against a real MongoDB?

Java seems to have such a [library](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo)

As part of the test, I would like to start embedded MongoDB and stop it at the end of the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no embedded MongoDB for Go as far as I am aware of.

What I do is to use mgo's own [gopkg.in/mgo.v2/dbtest](https://gopkg.in/mgo.v2/dbtest) which you can install as usual with

```
go get -u "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/dbtest"
```

Although it requires a `mongod` inside your $PATH, the dbtest takes care of all the rest.

You get a server with

```
package StackOverflowTests

import (
  "io/ioutil"
  "os"
  "testing"

  "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/dbtest"
)

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {

    d, _ := ioutil.TempDir(os.TempDir(), "mongotools-test")

    server := dbtest.DBServer{}
    server.SetPath(d)

    // Note that the server will be started automagically
    session := server.Session()

    // Insert data programmatically as needed
    setupDatabaseAndCollections(session)

    // Do your testing stuff
    foo.Bar(session)
    // Whatever tests you do

    // We can not use "defer session.Close()" because...
    session.Close()

    // ... "server.Wipe()" will panic if there are still connections open
    // for example because you did a .Copy() on the
    // original session in your code. VERY useful!
    server.Wipe()

    // Tear down the server
    server.Stop()
}
```

Note that you neither have to define an IP or port, which are provided automagically (a free open port in the non-reserved range of localhost is used).

Comment: There seems to be an issue with import for `gopkg.in/mgo.v2/dbtest`. When we run tests it fails with `gopkg.in/tomb.v2: no buildable Go source files in` error. I had to run `go get gopkg.in/tomb.v2` to resolve it.

Comment: @Olive.b Depends on your CI environment and your test scenario, I guess. At the end of the day `server.Session()` returns the same struct you would get from `mgo.Dial`. So it would be thinkable that you use a build tag integration tests, say `it`. You would then create two `*_test.go`, one with the above code and `!it`, and one with a connection to your MongoDB testcluster and the build tag `it`.

Comment: However, it is my sad duty to inform you that globalsign has ceased support for the driver, and it is getting out of date, already. See https://github.com/globalsign/mgo/issues/371#issuecomment-527873696